# Hacer click en otro lado del selector ocultar un elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando que cuando se haga click en otro lugar que fuera el botón, ocultar el div, pero no lo consigo, no tengo ni idea de cómo hacer.

```js
$(function(){
  
  $(document).on('click','#foo',function(){
    let div = $('#bar');
    if( div.css('display') === 'none' ){
      div.show();
    }
    
    else{
      div.hide();
    }
  });

})
```

```css
#foo{
  min-width: 35%;
}

#bar{
  max-width: 35%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="foo">Toggle</button><br><br>
<div id="bar"></div>
```

Se me ocurrió con

```
  $(document).on('click','html',function(e){
    if(e.eventTarget !== 'foo'){
      $('#bar').hide();
    }
  });
```

Pero en primera se traba la página y en segunda no está correcto el código, solo simula lo que pretendo conseguir.

Answer (score 0):

La forma que se te ocurrió es la correcta, sólo que en lugar de delegar al tag `html` debes delegarlo al `body`

```
$(document).on('click','body',function(e){
    if(e.eventTarget !== 'foo'){
      $('#bar').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes primero asociar el evento al body, para que coja todos los objetos que hay, y además debes controlar que el botón no continúe con el evento mediante [event.stopPropagation()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp);, evitando así que el evento se propague más abajo.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'body', function(e) {
  $('#bar').toggle();
});

$(document).on('click', 'button', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#foo {
  min-width: 35%;
}

#bar {
  max-width: 35%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="foo">Toggle</button><br><br>
<div id="bar"></div>
```